# Exception (cause) is always null in Hystrix feign fallback

Tags: hystrix, fallback, feign

I have an issue finding the exception cause in FallBackFactory, mine is a old application, so i can not use spring cloud approach (with annotations etc..)

I found the below solution, but still not working for me:
[Issue in getting cause in HystrixFeign client fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378073/issue-in-getting-cause-in-hystrixfeign-client-fallback/)

Here is the code i have:

```
public static class ProfileFallbackFactory implements ProfileProxy, FallbackFactory<ProfileFallbackFactory> {

    final Throwable cause;

    public ProfileFallbackFactory() {
        this(null);
    }

    ProfileFallbackFactory(Throwable cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }

    @Override
    public ProfileFallbackFactory create(Throwable cause) {
        LOG.info("Profile fallback create "+cause);

       return new ProfileFallbackFactory(cause);
    }

    public Profile getProfile(String id) {
  }
```

instance creation:

```
profileProxy = new HystrixFeign.Builder().setterFactory(new CustomSetterFactory())
                .decode404()
                .decoder(new GsonDecoder(gsonWithDateFormat))
                .encoder(new GsonEncoder(gsonWithDateFormat))
                .errorDecoder(new profileProxyErrorDecoder())
                .target(ProfileProxy.class,profileServiceUrl, (FallbackFactory<ProfileFallbackFactory>)new ProfileFallbackFactory());
```

There is a logger added in ProfileProxyErrorDecoder class, but this logger is not found in logs. I can see com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException in server logs

Can someone please point me where i am going wrong?